# Integration testing of a WordPress plugin that needs composer and npm to be executed

Tags: php, wordpress, unit-testing, phpunit, integration-testing

I am writing integration tests for a plugin, and I did everything using `wp-cli` and [scaffolding](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/scaffold/plugin-tests/) the tests. And they are running fine when I run `phpunit`. But the problem I have is that I am using `composer` and `npm` - composer for some extra functionality, and `npm` for bundling my scripts.

The scripts part is important because I'm enqueueing the scripts from the `public` folder (build folder)

```
$main_script = 'public/scripts/application.js';

wp_register_script( 'plugin-scripts', plugin_dir_url( __DIR__ ) . $main_script, array() );

wp_enqueue_script( 'plugin-scripts' );
```

I need to test if my scripts and styles are enqueued, so I added a test

```
public function test_enqueued_scripts() {
    $this->admin->enqueue_styles();
    $this->assertTrue( wp_script_is( 'plugin-scripts' ) );
}
```

`$this->admin` is just an instance of the class where my enqueue method is in the `setUp()` method.

And I get an error because it says that `Failed asserting that false is true.`

The plugin I'm testing is built and composer is installed. All the folders exist and everything works when I'm locally on my WordPress instance. But the test instance is not the same as my local instance (ofc). I `error_log`ed in the enqueue method to check if the `file_exist` and I get `false`.

I need to test this with phpunit (clients requirements are to have full test coverage).

My `bootstrap.php` looks like this

```
<?php
/**
 * PHPUnit bootstrap file
 *
 * @package Plugin
 */

$_tests_dir = getenv( 'WP_TESTS_DIR' );

if ( ! $_tests_dir ) {
  $_tests_dir = rtrim( sys_get_temp_dir(), '/\\' ) . '/wordpress-tests-lib';
}

if ( ! file_exists( $_tests_dir . '/includes/functions.php' ) ) {
  echo "Could not find $_tests_dir/includes/functions.php, have you run bin/install-wp-tests.sh ?" . PHP_EOL;
  exit( 1 );
}

// Give access to tests_add_filter() function.
require_once $_tests_dir . '/includes/functions.php';

/**
 * Manually load the plugin being tested.
 */
function _manually_load_plugin() {
  // Update array with plugins to include ...
  $plugins_to_active = array(
      'advanced-custom-fields-pro/acf.php',
      'my-plugin/my-plugin.php',
  );

  update_option( 'active_plugins', $plugins_to_active );

  require dirname( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) . '/advanced-custom-fields-pro/acf.php';
  require dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/my-plugin.php';
}
tests_add_filter( 'muplugins_loaded', '_manually_load_plugin' );

// Start up the WP testing environment.
require $_tests_dir . '/includes/bootstrap.php';
```

How can I start the build process (`npm run build`) so that my scripts exist before my unit tests? Also is it possible to have this build step run only once, not once every time I run `phpunit`?

Answer (score 2):

A very basic solution would be to check for a file that npm creates with `file_exists()` in your bootstrap.

If it aint there, run the build with `shell_exec()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: Inside the test or in the bootstrap?

Comment: in the boostrap!

Comment: So it turns out that in the boostrap.php, the directory points to the locally build plugin, but in my enqueue method, the `plugin_dir_url( __DIR__)` is `http://example.org/wp-content/plugins/Users/dingo_d/vagrant-local/www/projects/project/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/`. I have no idea where this `http://example.org/wp-content/plugins/` comes from...

Comment: `plugin_dir_url()` sounds like a method that takes `__DIR__`, and replaces the site root with the url.You don't want the URL, you want the `realpath()`

Comment: I mean I use it in the plugins, and it works fine, it's just acting weird in the unit tests. I'll see what it could be and report back.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts')` prior to executing your assertions. [This article](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-beginners-guide-to-unit-testing-building-testable-themes--wp-26007) has more details and an example. So, your test should look like this:

```php
public function test_enqueued_scripts() {
    $this->admin->enqueue_styles();
    do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts');
    $this->assertTrue( wp_script_is( 'plugin-scripts' ) );
}
```

I've tested this solution and it works.